# Azure - Disconnect VNet Integration in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, az

Through the Azure portal I can disconnect my VNet integration, see below.  I need to do this in a Powershell script, using the Az module.  Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
Remove-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "<resource-group-name>" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -ResourceName "<webapp-name>/virtualNetwork" -Force
```

Or

```
Remove-AzResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<webapp-name>/config/virtualNetwork" -Force
```

Comment: thanks for the information. Here is a follow up question you almost surely know the answer to:  https://superuser.com/q/1540059/1043540

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDagger Yeah, but I don't play that forum, could you post the question in stackoverflow and give me the link? It looks suitable for the `azure-resource-manager` tag.

Comment: sure thing.  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61112457/2860319 and thanks!

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDaggert Okay, I will post the answer later.