# How do you track down the Resource Type of a VNet Integration in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Yesterday I was trying to disconnect an App Service VNet integration in Powershell. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61090137/2860319), and I got an answer.  However, even if I knew the Powershell cmdlet specified in the solution, I would still be dependent on knowing that an App Service VNet integration has a resource type "Microsoft.Web/sites/config".  I don't know how to arrive at that information, and I will surely face similar questions in the future.

**Where is the resource type of a VNet Integration defined?  How do I access this information?**

- I've searched the Resource Explorer in the Portal and found nothing for VNet integration
- I've used the Export Template feature i the AppService blade.  There I see a resource type "Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections" which seems like it was what I needed, but it wasn't...
- I've tried to track it down using the Resource Graph Explorer with no luck
- I haven't found the right place to look in the Azure documentation, if there is one.

Maybe I've missed it, but it's definitely non-obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the resource type of the  VNet Integration, the trick is to use the developer tool to catch the request of the `OK` button below when you configure it.

1.Select the vnet and subnet, open the dev tool before click the `OK` button.

[image]

2.Click the `OK` button, you will be able to find the resource type `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` in the request response.

[image]